# jQuery find input checkbox in element in each

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to select a checkbox in all rows in a DataTables list on all pages. This is my code:

```
    $('#selectAll').click(function (e) {
        var p = oTableAPI.rows('tr', { page: 'all', "filter": "applied" }).nodes();
        $.each(p, function (i, e) {
            e.find('input[type = checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);
        });
    });
```

On this row i get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`:

```
e.find('input[type = checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

e is a reference to the DOM element, but is not a jQuery element and therefore doesn't have the $.find method

use `$(e)` or `$(this)`

```
$(e).find('input[type = checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);
```

EDIT `this.checked` points to the current element in the each loop. maybe save a checked variable, or use `var self = this;`

```
$('#selectAll').click(function (e) {
    var checked = this.checked;
    var p = oTableAPI.rows('tr', { page: 'all', "filter": "applied" }).nodes();
    $.each(p, function () {
        $(this).find('input[type = checkbox]').prop('checked', checked);
    });
});
```

Comment: When i console.log($(e)) i get "[tr.odd, context: tr.odd, jquery: "2.1.1", constructor: function, selector: "", toArray: function…]", is this correct? The checkbox does not get checked however...